# SISTEMA C# PARA AUTOMAIZAR CONSULTAS DE INFORMAÇÕES NO BANCO DE DADOS SQL

Tags: c#, sql

**Preciso trazer a informação que for preenchida no textbox2 para parâmetro '@ADATA ' e exibir todas as informações no datagridview**

**Segue ABAIXO código que apresentou erro, sou incitante e não estou conseguindo, agradeço ajuda**

```
            strSQL = "Select a.matricula, p.nome, p.cracha, m.data, m.status, Tipo = Case m.status When 0 then 'Entrada' Else 'Saída' end,m.evento, descricao  from dbo.tbPass p  join dbo.tbAlun a on a.id_pass = p.id_pass  join dbo.tbMovim m on p.id_Pass = m.id_pass                    And p.id_empresa = m.id_empresa  left join tbEventoSist e On m.evento = e.id_evento Where p.id_empresa = 1   And OBS = 'EAD'   And m.data >= @ADATA  and p.tipo = 'A' Order by a.matricula, m.data";

            comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conexao);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADATA", textBox2.Text);
            conexao.Open();
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();



            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conexao);

            conexao.Open();

            da.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexao.Close();
            conexao = null;
            comando = null;
        }
```

Comment: Bom dia! Aponte os detalhes do erro e em que linha ocorreu.

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta, e ela foi fechada por não estar adequada. É importante [seguir as instruções dadas a 1a vez que perguntou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/571911/70) e editar aquela postagem conforme orientado. Para evitar duplicidade de orientações, o campo de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na pergunta original, restaurando-a.